# Forms.WebBrowser Plugin installer coming up for each instance

Tags: vb.net, winforms, plugins, browser

I've been working on upgrading an application, and I've come upon two brick walls, although this question will only pertain to the first.

We allow users to add attachments from a web-based document service, so when the user clicks a button on one of the forms in our application, it opens up an instance of Forms.WebBrowser, which is essentially an IE wrapper. I've added a Value to the registry to make it run in IE8 compatibility mode, as this document service doesn't support IE7 compatibility mode (of which Forms.WebBrowser defaults to). This is the only change that I've made to the Forms.WebBrowser instance that I create.

When I open the WebBrowser, it instantly gives me a popup saying to install a plugin for the document service, of which I know for sure is already installed on my computer. I can click install or do not install, and it still appears to works fine. The problem is, this happens every single time I open the WebBrowser from the application, and I really don't want my users to come across this and become confused by what they have to press every time that they want to add an attachment from this document service.

Is there any way to make the WebBrowser reference the already installed plugins for my normal install of IE, or if this isn't possible, is there a way to automatically accept or decline the plugin installation (app is running in full-trust), or even a worst case scenario, can we make the Forms.WebBrowser block all popups, and just continue without the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [ScriptErrorsSuppressed Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed.aspx).  It should disable all dialog boxes, not just script errors.

Comment: Just tested it out, and this appears to work perfectly, and everything still appears on the page correctly. Thanks a lot!